# Is there a table package which automatically calculates the needed number of columns?

Tags: tables, xint

Is there a table package which automatically calculates the needed number of columns? Take for example this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}


\def\list{0,0.5,1,2.5,3,4.5,8}
\def\f(#1){#1^2}
\def\pf(#1){\pgfmathparse{\f(#1)}\num[round-precision=1,round-mode=places]{\pgfmathresult}}


\begin{tabular}{l|*{100}{c}} % Just choose 100, practically enough columns... but this ist not very elegant
  $x$ & \xintFor #1 in \list \do { & $#1$} \\\hline
  $f(x)$ & \xintFor #1 in \list \do { & $\pf(#1)$}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I can just choose 101 row numbers (large enough for pracical purposes), but this doesn't seem to be the correct way to do this. So is there any package which doesn't require the number of columns for this example?

Comment: that is exactly what amsmath does to avoid needing to specify the number of columns in matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using some large number in a `*` column repeat isn't so bad, it's how `amsmath` `matrix` avoids the need to specify columns, however if you want to access TeX's primitive feature of a `&&` meaning to repeat all following column specifications as often as needed then you can do something like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\d@llarend&\span\@gobbletwo}}
\makeatother

\def\list{0,0.5,1,2.5,3,4.5,8}
\def\f(#1){#1^2}
\def\pf(#1){\pgfmathparse{\f(#1)}\num[round-precision=1,round-mode=places]{\pgfmathresult}}


\begin{tabular}{l|?c}
  $x$ & \xintFor #1 in \list \do { & $#1$} \\\hline
  $f(x)$ & \xintFor #1 in \list \do { & $\pf(#1)$}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you use `&&`?

Comment: @Werner the array package added one and I dropped in another, and the `\span\@gobbletwo` made them come next to each other.

Comment: this deserves some LaTeX user interface!

Comment: @jfbu I'm upset that you don't consider my `&\span\@gobbletwo` as a high level well designed and intuitive latex user interface :(

Comment: I would were it not for the `@` `:)`